# Handle long time sorting in ag-grid (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am working with a big amount of data (1M - 5M), and rows in the grid should be groupable, sortable, and filterable. As ag-grid can populate table with data quickly enough, I use in-memory row model to satisfy requirements.

However, when I click column in order to sort all rows by this column, it takes some time to do this. Moreover, sequential clicking on columns while rows are still being sorted may crash grid as well as browser application.

Are there any ways to prevent user from clicking on columns (disable sorting, show loading overlay, or something like this)?

I am trying to use beforeSortChanged and afterSortChanged events to show overlay or modify DOM elements (to make grid a little bit grey and show loading circle), but it doesn't work properly: beforeSortChanged event handler seems to be stuck for a moment and then only executed.

Ag-grid is used inside Ember framework as a component.

Comment: Actually, it seems like sorting is done in short time, but then ag-grid refreshes its view that forces a web page to wait for it

Answer (score 0):

How about using [onCellClicked](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/index.php) which is an attribute of the columnDefs. Should work in a similar manner to what you are looking for with beforeSortChanged.

Comment: Thank you for a response. I tried this way, but it doesn't trigger the event when I click on column header.

Comment: ah right, no wonder I couldn't get it to work, haha. In that case you can use the [headerCellTemplate](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/index.php) and then put an onclick event in there to trigger anytime the header is clicked. I used this myself to customize an icon to toggle pinning.

Comment: It works, but still the same issue: need to wait for sorting completed first and only then the handler is executed.